# IF condition to show specific data to the logged in user

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to separate the view of a specific user from the system to a specific client. For example; The logged in user (user1 - ID_1) can only view the client data (client2 - ID_2). Is it possible to do this in an IF condition as in the example below?
(Id_users comes from the users table, and id_clients, from the clients table)

```
public function view() {
    if ($this-> 'id_users' = '1') {
        data['view'] =  'idclients' = '2';
    }

    $this->data['custom_error'] = '';
    $this->load->model('mapos_model');
    $this->data['result'] = $this->os_model->getById($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['products'] = $this->os_model->getProducts($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['services'] = $this->os_model->getServices($this->uri->segment(3));
    $this->data['emitent'] = $this->mapos_model->getEmitent();

    $this->data['view'] = 'os/viewOs';
    $this->load->view('theme/top', $this->data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use session .any place to your project

```
if($this->session->userdata('session_name')){
   echo "Your specific data";
}
else{
echo "Others Data";
}
```

Comment: I do not understand your example. Could it explain better in my case to specific users and clients?